# How concatenate a array of videos using avconv

Tags: php, ubuntu, terminal, libavcodec, avcodec

I want to concatenate a array of videos my array is

```
$interFIFO // array(
               0=>test1.mpg,
               1=>test2.mpg,
               2=>test3.mpg,
               3=>test4.mpg,
              );// array count may be increase some time
```

I know concatenate 2 video files and its working file my code is

```
shell_exec("cat test1.mpg test2.mpg > test_all.mpg");
```

The above code working file and i got result.

My problem is **concatenate more than 2 videos** using php and **avconv**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your method to concatenate 2 videos works why u won't try this:

```
 shell_exec("cat ".implode(" ", $interFIFO)." > test_all.mpg");
```

Implode concatenates elements of array with 'glue' as first parameter (in this case it's space ' ')

Comment: i want to concatenate more than 2 videos